# Race in exception propagation with std::future::unwrap

Tags: c++, promise, future, race-condition, c++20

Going off the paper about improvements to `std::future`'s API here [n3721](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2013/n3721.pdf).  There seems to be a race in exception propagation with respect to unwrapped futures.  The document says

> If the outer future throws an exception, and .get() is called on the returned future, the returned future throws the same exception as the outer future. This is the case because the inner future didn’t exit

So what I mean is in a case like the following

```
#include <iostream>
#include <future>
#include <exception>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    auto prom_one = std::promise<std::future<int>>{};
    auto fut_one = prom_one.get_future();

    std::thread{[prom_one = std::move(prom_one)]() mutable {
        auto prom_two = std::promise<int>{};
        auto fut_two = prom_two.get_future();
        std::thread{[prom_two = std::move(prom_two)]() mutable {
            prom_two.set_exception(std::make_exception_ptr(std::logic_error{}));
        }}.detach();
        prom_one.set_exception(std::make_exception_ptr(std::bad_alloc{}));
    }}.detach();


    auto inner_fut = fut_one.unwrap();
    cout << inner_fut.get() << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

The race I was talking about earlier is - which exception will be thrown?  The inner `std::logic_error` or the outer `std::bad_alloc`?

Am I getting this wrong?  Is there no race in the above code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I realized that the code above does not have any race, since with a nested future - `std::future<std::future<int>>` there are only two possibilities, either the inner future has been set via a call to `std::promise::set_value` or an exception has been set and the inner future is not linked to the outer future at all (as is in the code above).

If the inner future has not been linked then the outer future's exception will be the exception that is thrown.  And if the inner future has been linked there is no scope for the outer future throwing because the outer future's promise has already called `set_value` with the inner future once, so setting an exception after that on the outer future itself is invalid (which will cause an exception itself to be thrown).

I think this is what the paper talked about when it said

> This is the case because the inner future didn’t exit